# Sequence vs SQL Query

Tags: sql, oracle, sequence

Could someone explain me which is better and faster in Oracle - Sequence or SQL Query? Will Sequence work faster or a Query to get next sequence no., will work faster?

Comment: Add Oracle Flag, it  will be usefull to help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How you are planning to generate a sequence with query?

Are you planning to write some thing like `select max(id)+1 from mytable;` ?
Then please don't it will put you in much deep in trouble than performance issue. While saving data with concurrent connection it will generate same sequence for multiple insert statement which all but one will eventually fail if you have primary key or unique key constraint on the column. If you don't then you will end up with same sequence for multiple transactions which is far worse than transaction failure.

So it's better to have a sequence with cache.

Comment: OK, thank you.  Yes I am planning similar to select max(id)+1 from mytable.  Thank you for answering Sequence is better.

Comment: Please don't use select max(id)+1. It only works if you are always using single connection at a time which is not practical at all. Please accept this answer by clicking green check if it helped your.

Comment: OK, sure, I will go by Sequence

Comment: Thanks. Best wishes.